# Loading js dynamically not working the same on different apps

Tags: angular

I have two angular app that share the same code for loading a js script:

```
loadTableauScript() {
    const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://url_to_js';
    script.onload = () => {
      console.log('script loaded');
      this.scriptLoaded = true
    };
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, script);
  }
```

In one app is working in the other one it is not, I don't see any error in the developer console. Since the `angular.json` file is pretty different in the two apps I'm wondering if that could be the cause.

What are the aspect that affects a js dynamic loading in angular? Configurations? LazyModules?

I know that the question need to provide more details but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Have you checked if that method is actually being called?

Comment: it is and I see from the network tab of the dev console that the script is loaded